Rook endgame with pawns on each flank
Why is Rc2 the only winning move?
[Title ""]
[Fen "8/5R2/6p1/3k3p/7P/p3K1P1/r4P2/8 b - - 0 1"]


Trying some lines on the public Stockfish 16.1 at
nextchessmove.com, it seems that the critical line comes down to White giving up the Rook to counterattack with Kf4, Kg5 etc., and Black has to start with Rc2 rather than Rb2 to avoid wasting a tempo in some variations by blocking Kb2.

I'll download that Stockfish 16.1 thanks, I'm a bit tired of Leela. This type of simple endgames drive me crazy. I guess it's not difficult but when everything changes in matters of a single tempi I have a hard time considering all the alternatives.

@samchanclas this endgame is the opposite of simple!!
